# How to address to a file in near folder

Tags: php, path, include

I have two folder in my project folder like this:

```
-my project folder
      -folder1
              file1.php
      -folder2
              file2.php
```

in `file1.php` I want to import `file2.php` so I write this:

```
include_once '../folder2/file2.php';
```

but it show me an error:

> include_once(../folder2/file2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

What is solution?

**ANSWER:**

```
include_once(__DIR__ . ".\..\folder2\file2.php");
```

I want it's reason?

Comment: The invocation script (index.php) usually determines the current working directory, which all include calls must be relative to.

Comment: Does you call `file1.php` or does the file `file1.php` also get's included to another file?

Comment: in a file in root of project folder I include `file1.php` and in `file1.php` I try to include `file2.php` that I faced with error

Comment: Indeed `file2.php` is a library that I want to use it in `file1.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "../folder2/file2.php");
```

Or (from PHP 5.3):

```
include_once(__DIR__ . "../folder2/file2.php");
```

PHP's `include` mechanism searches files from the "current directory" view instead of the "current file's directory". In general, "current directory" is the main file's (eg. index.php) directory. You can change it by calling `chdir()` or some related function. `dirname(__FILE__)` (or `__DIR__`) means the "current file's directory".

An other possible solution is, when you define the root folder, and include everything relative to this:

In index.php:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
```

Everywhere:

```
include(ROOT_DIR . "somedir/somefile.php");
```

You can use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` too, but I do not recommend this.

In larger projects it is recommended to programming with OOP. With object oriented code you can use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-unregister.php).

Comment: it work with: `include_once(__DIR__ . ".\..\folder2\file2.php");` and I don't it's reason?

Comment: It is recommended to use `/` (slash) (or, in some cases, the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant) instead of `\\` (backslash) - regardless of the system.